# Add class to List item but changes over time

Tags: jquery

I have a list of tweets as list items.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Tweet 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tweet 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tweet 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to get the first tweet to show then change after say 5 seconds.

I am not sure what you call this and have been searching the web for over 4 hours now. Its not a feed because I already have the list of tweets but I am not sure what to use to get the effect I want.

Please can you point out what this is called so I can finally research the correct thing.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an ID for the `ul` element so you can find it easily:

```
<ul id="tweetList">
<li><a href="#">Tweet 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Tweet 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Tweet 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

then, you can do this:

```
var firstTweet = $('#tweetList li:first()');
firstTweet.addClass('tempClass'); //add the class
setTimeout(function(){
    //after 5k ms, remove it.
    firstTweet.removeClass('tempclass');
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that!

Would you then just write 3 more of the same to run at diffrent times? or how would you run through each list item to show and hide?

If you can point me in the direction to maybe what I need to read more about It will be massive help. I want to learn more about this stuff.